# mockRequest variable usage inside a soapui teststep

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am using `soapui` for testing a `REST` application. I want to know is it possible to call mockRequest variable inside a groovy teststep?

I have the following groovy script:

```java
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.WsdlMockResult;

def queryString = mockRequest.getHttpRequest().getQueryString()
def httpResponse = mockRequest.httpResponse
//log.info "HTTP Response is: "+httpResponse
def mediaType = mockRequest.getHttpRequest().getHeader("Content-Type")  
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)

//This variable is used to get the soapui project path
def path = groovyUtils.projectPath + "/mockResponse/"

if (mockRequest.getMethod() == "POST" && mediaType=="application/xml"){
    def notifyRequest = mockRequest.requestContent
    def notifyXml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(notifyRequest)

    String representation = notifyXml.representation

    def decoded = new String(representation.decodeBase64())
    log.info "The decoded data received is: "+decoded

    new File("E:\\some_folder\\mockResponse\\1.xml").withWriter{ it << decoded } 

    WsdlMockResult mockResult = new WsdlMockResult(mockRequest)
     def Response = mockRequest.httpResponse
     httpResponse.setContentLength(0)
     Response.status = 200
     return mockResult

}
```

Actually I want to achieve a result such that whenever a message is received on `MockService` then appropriate response should be sent. Also, I want to save some data from the request message received. This functionality is different for each test case hence I need to do it in groovy test step instead of onRequest tab of mockService.

Does anyone has any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

To customize your Mock Service's response have a look at [soapUI's guide on the same](http://www.soapui.org/Getting-Started/mock-services.html#5-customizing-a-mockresponse). You will have access to the request received by the Mock Service in the script section of the service.

My question though is, if you are using a mock service why do you want to save anything from the request received?

Comment: I want to extract this information and decode it. Later I need to compare this information and judge the result of my test case. Hence I need to read the mockRequest variable via a test step.

Comment: Do you mean I can access mockRequest in a test step? Sorry I didn't understood "script section of the service"?? :\

Comment: when you create a mock operation you will see a script tab at the bottom. Check out the soapUI link i provided in my answer.

Comment: As for decoding the information, the information you receive at the mock service will be the request you sent to it. What information do you want to compare when you are the one sending that information.